# Need to pass parameter from partial render to a javascript function in .html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I will post only the relevant snippet of the file

**index.html.erb**

```
  <%= render "trace/outbound_message", error => @msg_error,:selector => "#ui-accordion-accordion-panel-3", :tab => "ui-id-1" %>
```

**_outbound_message.html.erb**

```
<% unless error.blank? %>
<%= error.html_safe %>
<script>
    $(function() {
        show_error(<% selector %>,<% tab %>);
    });
</script>
<%end%>
```

But this function is not able to be called successfully, as I don't think js undersands the embedded ruby code. What is my quickest workaround? Do I have to call a js.erb file, and how do I pass parameters to & in it?

UPDATE
I changed the script to

```
 <script>
  alert("check-up");
    $(function() {
        show_error(<%= selector %>,<%= tab %>);
    });
   </script>
```

And even that alert is not being shown? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ruby code in a block like:

**In Ruby code:**

```
v = "show_error(<%= selector %>,<%= tab %>);"
```

**In javascript:**

```
<script>
    $(function() {

     $(#{v});

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not working, How is $(#{v}) suppose to work? Inside the javascript file, how will you parse #{v} ...Not ruby dude.

Comment: I just posted the solution...You were very close.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you quotes ! You should have something like this

```
show_error(foo,bar);
```

and you need something like

```
show_error('foo','bar');
```

And don't forget to escape your JS :

```
show_error('<%= escape_javascript(@selector) %>', '<%= escape_javascript(@tab) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
<script>
alert("check-up");
$(function() {
  show_error(<%= selector.to_json %>,<%= tab.to_json %>);
});
</script>
```

The `to_json` function will wrap your variable between quotes, that were missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around, and I figured it out.

```
  <%=  javascript_tag( "$(function() {show_error('#{selector}','#{tab}');});")%>
```

The javascript_tag played a vital role. You can't enclose it in ...

Btw @Saurabh - You were exceptionally close to the answer, no idea why somebody down-voted you.